# excel VBA how to make a floating button?

Tags: excel, button, floating, vba

have a code that check the date and fill cells with appropriate colors and this code includes a button that when the user clicked it will run the VBA code.

i want to always make the button visible no matter how the user scroll down.

## code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'Range upto 5000, chnge this as per your requirment'


    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
         Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = xlNone

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) < 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) = 0 Then
             Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 1 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 4 Then
              Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

       ElseIf (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) >= 5 And (VBA.CDate(Cells(i, 3)) - VBA.Date()) <= 10 Then
               Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbCyan

    Else
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

 End If

    ' your 2nd criteria to color the entire row if "F" is not empty
    If Trim(Range("F" & i).Value) <> "" Then Range("D" & i & ":F" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Debug.Print Len(Range("F" & i).Value)


Next
End Sub
```

i will appreciate any help.

Comment: What sort of button is it? Form control or ActiveX?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie  form control

Comment: Three possible solutions: (1) place the button in a ribbon / menu (2) place the button in the top row and fixate that row (view --> freeze pane) or (3) put the button on a form and show the form with modal being `False`.

Comment: Freeze panes is easier

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
        CommandButton1.Top = .Top + 100
        CommandButton1.Left = .Left + 300
    End With
End Sub
```